# The operator < is undefined for the argument type(s) int, Dimension error while creating a list of webelements using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, list, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Getting this error while printing all links in Selenium. Need help where the actual issue is on this line(Learning from online tutorial), what are the alternative options:

```
List<WebElement> alltags = (List<WebElement>) driver.findElement(By.tagName("a"));
```

Code block:

```
package ui;
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;

public class PrintAllLinks {

    public static String browser = "chrome"; //Which Browser you want to Test?
    public static WebDriver driver;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        if(browser.equals("Firefox"))
        {
            WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        } else if(browser.equals("chrome"))
        {
            WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
        } else if(browser.equals("edge"))
        {
            WebDriverManager.edgedriver().setup();
            driver = new EdgeDriver();
        }
        
        driver.get("https://www.sugarcrm.com/request-demo/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        List<WebElement> alltags = (List<WebElement>) driver.findElement(By.tagName("a"));
        System.out.println("Total tags are" + alltags.size());
        
        for(int i=0; i<alltags.size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Links on page are" +alltags.get(i).getAttribute("href"));
            System.out.println("Links on page are" +alltags.get(i).getText());
        }
        
        driver.close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

### findElements()

[`findElements()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElements(org.openqa.selenium.By)) returns a list of all matching [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139)s, or an empty list if nothing matches.

So you need to make two changes as follows:

- Instead of `findElement()` use `findElements()`
- Remove the explicit casting to `List<WebElement>`.

Effectively, your line of code will be:

```
List<WebElement> alltags =  driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
```